# Angular CLI - Get coverage report to include all sources

Tags: angular, angular-cli, karma-runner, karma-coverage

I am trying to figure out how to include all my .ts sources in the generated coverage report from the angular CLI. Currently I am only getting coverage for files that have an associated spec with tests against.

I have tried adding the `includeAllSources` flag to my karma.conf.js file but this made no difference.

Whats the correct approach here? I am using Angular CLI 6.1.5

Thanks

Comment: I've updated the sourceRoot in angular.json, and it worked for me.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The simplest solution that worked for me on Angular(v6) was just adding a `app.module.spec.ts` file to compliment your `app.module.ts` and within that .spec include the following code

`import './app.module';`

Apparently due to the fact `app.module.ts` is the root of your application including a .spec for that module will result in the inclusion of all your files during code coverage (`ng test --code-coverage`)

Comment: Used same Workaround as the answer above in my Angular 8 project. For each lazy loaded module I added a seperate testfile analogous to app.module.spec.ts.

Comment: I am having a small Angular library. At the end of the `test.ts`, I've added an export: `export * from './public-api';`

Answer (score 5):

[Solution provided by Narm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52103042/4335221) is really great, however still not ideal, as requires importing manually at least all the lazy loaded modules + root one to the tests and also on big projects there are almost always some non-used/forgotten components which are not part of any production code and which will leave in the source code for ever untested/undiscovered.

**Solution:**

https://github.com/kopach/karma-sabarivka-reporter.

To use it → install `npm install --save-dev karma-sabarivka-reporter`

And update `karma.conf.js` as described here https://github.com/kopach/karma-sabarivka-reporter#-usage

After this – all files matching pattern will be included into final coverage result

Comment: This works great. I had to add `require('karma-sabarivka-reporter')` to the `plugins` array in `karma.conf.js` to make it work. The Lines coverage went from 434/4201 to 38/6589, which is a little weird because the lines covered should not have changed. However, when i `cloc src/app` my app, it says 11,745 lines of TypeScript. So it seems there are still a lot of LOC not being counted.

Comment: @alexraasch, please, make sure your configuration doesn't include "too much". Only needed source code files should be included. See Usage section of plugin's Readme page. As for LOC – try karma-html-reporter, and go through generated HTML reports to see what's exactly added to coverage.

Comment: curious how people are handling this with jest?  Somewhat similar in the jest.config file?